# Git is renaming files as if there's a duplicate, but there isn't (PhpStorm)

Tags: git, duplicates, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, file-rename

I'm having an issue with Git in PhpStorm. I'm connected to my own branch in Git and I have this file called `Bestelvalidatie.jsx`. Every few minutes my Chrome gives me the error 'Bestelvalidatie.jsx not found' and when I look in PhpStorm it renamed the file to `Bestelvalidatie 1.jsx`. Every time I rename the file it ups the number after the file, we're at 11 now already.

I've already tried to copy the code, delete the file, new file with same name, paste code --> didn't work.

I've tried to remove the file in my own branch, git add, commit & push, new file, paste code --> didn't work.

I've tried to remove the file from Bitbucket, git pull. Add new file in PhpStorm, paste code, git push --> didn't work.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Git does not do this, but some other software you're using might.

Comment: I am positive that this is not PhpStorm either - we just don't have such a feature, at least by default. You need to check what process is creating the files, ways to do that differ depending on the OS.